# Qt License now after Digia bought it

Tags: c++, qt

What is the license of Qt platform (Qt libraries, QT Creator, Designer, Linguist etc) after Digia bought it from Nokia?

Is it still LGPL? Are they planning to enforce their own commercial license? Or will there be three versions of it (GPL/LGPL/Commercial)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Digia's Qt Commercial Blog](http://www.digia.com/en/Blogs/Qt-blog/Tuukka-Turunen/Dates/2012/8/Digia-extends-commitment-to-acquire-Qt-from-Nokia/)

> **Committed to both commercial and open-source licensing**
>
> Since we
>   acquired the commercial licensing business of Qt a bit more than a
>   year ago the Digia Qt R&D team has been hard at work developing and
>   releasing not only new and updated features and functions for Qt
>   Commercial customers, but also working together with the Qt Project
>   building and releasing both the commercial and LGPL releases,
>   contributing documentation, bug fixes and improvements mainly to the
>   desktop and embedded platforms.
>   ...
>
> With this acquisition Digia will have an increasing responsibility to
>   the global Qt community, not just the commercial licensing business.
>   We believe in the power of the Qt dual license. It is a great value
>   for Qt that it can be used under an open source and commercial
>   license, since customers have different needs and the licenses have
>   different purposes. Digia wants to continue the good co-operation with
>   different individual contributors and companies working together in
>   the Qt Project. We also are committed to continuing the special
>   relationship Qt has with the KDE community via the KDE Free Qt
>   Foundation. We believe that this symbiosis is valuable for everyone
>   involved.
>   ...
>   We want to work with the entire Qt ecosystem through
>   the Qt Project to make sure that Qt will continue to thrive both under
>   commercial and open-source licenses.

Sounds like they want to keep things running the way they are and focus on making the commercial and open source communities even stronger.

Comment: Haven't Digia been running commercial licensing for QT for some time anyway?  

Qt now clearly has a focus back on the desktop. Almost certainly a good thing.